# Marking records with 1 on first occurence of unique value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that I'd like to add a column to that shows a 1 on the first occurrence of a given value for the record within the dataset.

So, for example, if I was using the `ID` field as where to look for unique occurrences, I'd want a "FirstOccur" column (like the one below) putting a 1 on the first occurrence of a unique `ID` value in the dataset and just ignoring (leaving as null) any other occurrence:

```
|  ID  |  FirstOccur  |
|------|--------------|
|  1   |      1       |
|  1   |              |
|  1   |              |
|  2   |      1       |
|  2   |              |
|  3   |      1       |
|  4   |      1       |
|  4   |              |
```

I have a working 2-step approach that first applies some ranking sql that will give me something like this:

```
|  ID  |  FirstOccur  |
|------|--------------|
|  1   |      1       |
|  1   |      2       |
|  1   |      3       |
|  2   |      1       |
|  2   |      2       |
|  3   |      1       |
|  4   |      1       |
|  4   |      2       |
```

..and I just apply some update SQL to null any value above 1 to get the desired result.

I was just wondering if there was a (simpler) one-hit approach.

Comment: Do you have a unique id on each row?  Or, at least some way to determine the ordering?

Comment: I don't have a unique ID, but I could order by the `ID` field shown in the question so that it is in some order.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a creation date or auto incremented id or something that specifies the ordering, you can do:

```
update t
    set firstoccur = 1
    where creationdate = (select min(creationdate)
                          from t as t2
                          where t2.id = t.id 
                         );
```

Comment: I'd only want to specify the ordering on the ID field itself.. when I replace `creationdate` with `ID` it just puts a 1 in `firstoccurr` against every record in the dataset.

Comment: @MattHall . . . That is because `id` is repeated in your table.   You need a column that specifies the ordering for each `id`.